# Включить поддержку SSL/TLS в браузере elinks

Tags: linux, ssl, https, браузер, terminal

Привет, Мир!

Я установил консольный (текстовый) браузер  **elinks** на Ubuntu 16.04. Пробовал войти на *vk.com* Там мне сказали, что браузер не поддерживает JavaScript. Я переустановил elinks по [этой инструкции](http://www.cnx-software.com/2014/02/09/building-elinks-text-based-web-browser-with-some-sort-of-javascript-support/). Включил в настройках JavaScript. Но теперь тот же *vk.com* даже открыть не получается из-за ошибки показанной на изображении ниже.

[image: ошибка при открытии https страницы]

**Вопрос**: Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы заработали https ссылки?

Comment: Проверьте, что в конце работы скрипта `./configure` есть упоминания об SSL (удобно для этого использовать поиск в окне терминала). Если это не так, убедитесь, что установлен пакет **libssl-dev** либо **libgnutls-dev** (на ваш выбор).

Comment: @mymedia Спасибо! Помогла установка **libssl-dev** и добавление "-lssl" к команде **make** после повторной "./configure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте, что в конце работы скрипта `./configure` есть упоминания об SSL (удобно для этого использовать поиск в окне терминала). Если это не так, убедитесь, что установлен пакет [libssl-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libssl-dev) либо [libgnutls-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libssl-dev) (на ваш выбор, по сути различия там только в лицензиях). Никаких дополнительных параметров утилите **make** передавать нет надобности.